# Objective-C: Popover seems to be always nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sketchapp-plugin

I'm currently writing a plugin for SketchApp with cocoa.

I try to use a `NSPopover` there, that should get triggered by an `IBAction` when clicking on a button. Problem is: the popover does not show up, and when inspecting the variable, that should hold the popover, it is `nil`.

I created the `NSPopover` in the Interface Builder, so not programmatically in code; then defined an `IBOutlet` binding in my linked classes header file; and finally use this variable inside my implementation class.

Here is my source code:

**MyComponent.h**

```
// imports skipped...

@interface

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *componentDescription;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *componentGuid;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSButton *guidCopyButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;

-(IBAction)onCopyButton_Clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

**MyComponent.m**

```
-(IBAction)onCopyButton_Clicked:(id)sender {

    // copy stuff to clipboard
    // [...]

    // show copied popover
    [_popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] 
                          ofView:sender 
                   preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

In my `xib`-view-file, I linked the NSPopover-Object to the `IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;`. But when inspecting `_popover` in my class implementation it is always `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after tweeking things around a bit, I guess I finally understood what went wrong. After changing the memory mode from `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSPopover *popover;` to `... (nonatomic, strong) ...;` the instance is not `nil` anymore.

I think the difference to the `NSButton` (for example) here is, that the button is **used** in the xib template, so the button's reference does not get cleaned up. The Popover however is not directly "used", so it may gets cleaned up, before it could get actually used. So, changing it from `weak` to `strong` seems to be the point here.

**However:** Does this tweak have unexpected / unintended side effects I probably want to address somehow? Do I have to care for the destruction on my own for the popover now?

Comment: References to non primary objects  in XIBs generally need to be strong. If you connected the outlet by dragging from IB rather than writing it in code it should have done that. `MyComponent` owns the popover so it’s correct that it should be strong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I'm new to cocoa and in general C / Objective C, so this was an important thing for me to realize for future :)

Comment: Yep. It’s not easy to work out sometimes. The buttons and text fields can be weak because they are part of a view hierarchy but your popover that I assume is floating as second object in the XIB needs an owner. :-)